# What is the biblical basis for tithing and NOT keeping the Sabbath at the same time?

Tags: biblical-basis, sabbath, law-and-gospel, tithe

Many (most?) churches encourage their members to tithe (let's call these churches A), and many have a biblical basis for it, e.g.:

- [According to Reformed Theology, what is the doctrinal basis for belief in New Testament tithing?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/62509/50422)
- [What is the biblical basis for the claim that Malachi 3:6-12's curse and blessings concerning tithing apply to the New Testament Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/87050/50422)

Similarly, many (most?) churches do NOT keep the sabbath (let's call these churches B), and many of them have a biblical basis for it as well, e.g.:

- [What is the biblical basis for NOT keeping a literal physical Sabbath rest every seventh day?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/82507/50422)
- [What is the biblical basis for believing that the Feast Days / Appointed Festivals / Holy Convocations are NOT morally binding for Christians today?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84626/50422)

Now, I'm curious about those churches in the intersection between A and B, namely, those that encourage tithing AND do not keep the Sabbath **at the same time**. I'm struggling to see how this could possibly be a self-consistent position to hold. Both tithing and sabbath keeping were Old Testament laws, so if I were somehow forced to defend tithing as a law still binding on New Testament Christians, I'm unable to think of a single argument that wouldn't also lead to the unescapable conclusion that sabbath keeping is also binding. In my (possibly uninformed) opinion, if we have to tithe, then we have to keep the sabbath too.

**Question**: What is the biblical basis for tithing and NOT keeping the Sabbath AT THE SAME TIME?

Comment: I like the question, but not to rain on your parade, [biblical basis questions need to show *actual* use by a group / church](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/10672), not simply a *hypothetical* position.  Reading [@SLM's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89129/10672) leads me to doubt whether an actual church teaches this.  In the meantime, no -1, just close vote.

Comment: To preserve the integrity of `biblical-basis` tag while recognizing that many churches practice this, maybe the question can be rephrased as "Is there a biblical basis" or "What is the justification of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

One answer could be that tithing is shown before the Law of Moses between Abram and Melchizedek.

> And blessed be the most high God, which hath delivered thine enemies into thy hand. And he gave him tithes of all. Gen 14:20

But then, so was the Sabbath wherein God sanctified the seventh day.

> And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made. And God blessed the seventh day, and sanctified it: because that in it he had rested from all his work which God created and made. Gen 2:2-3

Another answer is that if you don't tithe, you are cursed.

> Will a man rob God? Yet ye have robbed me. But ye say, Wherein have we robbed thee? In tithes and offerings. Ye are cursed with a curse: for ye have robbed me, even this whole nation. Malachi 3:8-9

But then if you don't keep the Sabbath, you are likewise cursed.

> But it shall come to pass, if thou wilt not hearken unto the voice of the LORD thy God, to observe to do all his commandments and his statutes which I command thee this day; that all these curses shall come upon thee, and overtake thee: Deut 28:15

So, to attempt an answer to the OP, there is no biblical basis to tithe, but not observe the Sabbath.