# Are there any churches that encourage their members to tithe but not to keep the Sabbath (Friday sunset to Saturday sunset)?

Tags: denomination-survey, reference-request, sabbath, tithe, doctrine

My common sense tells me that there must be many such churches, but I'm having a hard time finding concrete examples on the web where this is officially stated in their doctrinal statement of faith.

Does anyone know concrete examples that can be backed up with references?

---

Note: by "keeping the Sabbath" I mean from Friday sunset to Saturday sunset, according to Exodus 20:8-11 (ESV)'s instructions:

> 8 “Remember the Sabbath day, to keep it holy. 9 Six days you shall labor, and do all your work, 10 but the seventh day is a Sabbath to the Lord your God. On it you shall not do any work, you, or your son, or your daughter, your male servant, or your female servant, or your livestock, or the sojourner who is within your gates. 11 For in six days the Lord made heaven and earth, the sea, and all that is in them, and rested on the seventh day. Therefore the Lord blessed the Sabbath day and made it holy.

Isaiah 58:13-14 (ESV) sheds more light on this commandment:

> 13 “If you turn back your foot from the Sabbath,
> from doing your pleasure on my holy day,
> and call the Sabbath a delight
> and the holy day of the Lord honorable;
> if you honor it, not going your own ways,
> or seeking your own pleasure, or talking idly;
> 14 then you shall take delight in the Lord,
> and I will make you ride on the heights of the earth;
> I will feed you with the heritage of Jacob your father,
> for the mouth of the Lord has spoken.”

---

Related: [What is the biblical basis for tithing and NOT keeping the Sabbath at the same time?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89124/50422)

Comment: Can you clarify your meaning of 'keeping the Sabbath? Does Chick-fil-a keep the Sabbath by closing on Sundays?

Comment: @bradimus - thanks for the question. I added a couple of quotes from Scripture clarifying the meaning.

Comment: I think it still needs an explicit "Friday sunset to Saturday sunset" definition. It's not unusual for Sunday to be referred to as "the Sabbath".  See recent historical instances of "blue laws", that restrict civil behaviour on the Sunday Sabbath day.  E.g. [Never on a Sunday - Canada's History](https://www.canadashistory.ca/explore/arts-culture-society/never-on-a-sunday)

Comment: @RayButterworth - Thanks for the suggestion. Edited accordingly.